# chrome.bookmarks.onRemoved listener not called

Tags: javascript, api, firefox-addon

Trying to use [chrome.bookmarks.onRemoved](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks#event-onRemoved) from the chrome.bookmarks api in a Firefox extension:

```
chrome.bookmarks.onRemoved.addListener(function (id, removeInfo) {
    "use strict";
    checkIfBookmarked();
});
```

This is to catch manual removal of bookmarks by user, but `checkIfBookmarked()` is never called when bookmark is removed, regardless whether the deletion is manual or programmatic.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm lost.  You can use a Chrome extension API in a Firefox extension?

Comment: @Archer, yes Mozilla is replacing add-ons by [webExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/Add-ons/WebExtensions).

Comment: Wow.  I had no idea - thanks!

Comment: The link you gave sadly answers your own question.  `onRemoved` is not available in Firefox yet... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Browser_support_for_JavaScript_APIs

Comment: Okay, I've added an answer, just so there's a definite question/answer here.  It's a shame but I'm sure it won't be forever.  It's still great progress, regardless.

Comment: @mins, It is not clear that they are completely *replacing* all other extension types with WebExtensions.  They have announced plans to deprecate extensions which are not either based on the Add-on SDK or WebExtensions.

Comment: @Makyen: That's correct, though the tendency is to [move from XUL to JS](http://www.zdnet.com/article/mozilla-changes-firefox-apis-developers-unhappy/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly Firefox doesn't support that event yet, as can be seen here...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks/onRemoved

As you can see from the full compatibility list there's still quite a bit left to do, but it's on the right track so hopefully it won't be too long...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Browser_support_for_JavaScript_APIs